# `async function` как узнать что функция асинхронная или промис

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

вопрос рассматривается **в контексте нативного кода**
**без** вавилонских башен и прочих **транспилеров**!

зачем это может быть нужно?

вот простой пример
есть функция, для замера времени выполнения другой функции

```
/**
 * @param _f функция
 */
test(_f) {
    if (!_f) throw new TypeError('!_f')
    let result = null                   // результат выполнения функции
    let time = null
    try {
        time = performance.now()         // засекаем время
        result = _f()                    // вызоваем тестируемую функциию
        time = performance.now() - time  // вычисляем время
    } catch (_e) {
        time = null
        console.log(_e)
    }
    return time
}
```

есть три тестируемые функции

```
function foo() { return 'res' }
async function bar() { return 'res' }
function baz() { return Promise.resolve('res') }
```

если мы попробуем их "протестировать"

```
console.log('foo',lib.test(foo))//foo 0.10000006295740604
console.log('bar',lib.test(bar))//bar 0.20000000949949026
console.log('baz',lib.test(baz))//baz 0.09999994654208422
```

то мы получим результат, он даже **будет похож** на настоящий, НО **ЭТО НЕ ТАК**

```js
void function() {
  /**
   * @param _f функция
   */
  let test = (_f) => {
    if (!_f) throw new TypeError('!_f')
    let result = null // результат выполнения функции
    let time = null
    try {
      time = performance.now() // засекаем время
      result = _f() // вызоваем тестируемую функциию
      time = performance.now() - time // вычисляем время
    } catch (_e) {
      time = null
      console.log(_e)
    }
    return [time, result]
  }

  function foo() {
    return 'res'
  }
  async function bar() {
    return 'res'
  }

  function baz() {
    return Promise.resolve('res')
  }

  console.log('foo', test(foo)) //foo (2) [0.10000006295740604, "res"]
  console.log('bar', test(bar)) //bar (2) [0.09999994654208422, Promise] //<-- !!!Promise
  console.log('baz', test(baz)) //baz (2) [0.09999994654208422, Promise] //<-- !!!Promise
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

и так.
для начала пример кода, который обнаруживает промис или асинхронную функцию и в этом случае `time` и `result` присваивает `null`.

прошу обратить внимание на два блока:

- `#region проверка на страрте`
- `#region проверка в процессе`

```js
void function() {
  /**
   * @param _f функция
   */
  let test = (_f) => {

    //#region проверка на страрте
    if (!_f || !(_f instanceof Function)) throw new TypeError('!_f of _f not Function')
    // --
    // if (_f[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction') throw new TypeError('AsyncFunction')
    // --
    // const AsyncFunction = (async () => {}).constructor;
    // if (_f instanceof AsyncFunction) throw new TypeError('AsyncFunction')
    // --
    //#endregion проверка на страрте

    let isPromiseOrAsync = (_f) => (_f == Promise.resolve(_f)) //проверка в процессе

    let result = null // результат выполнения функции
    let time = null // время выполнения
    try {
      time = performance.now() // засекаем время
      result = _f() // вызоваем тестируемую функциию
      time = performance.now() - time // вычисляем время

      //#region проверка в процессе
      if (isPromiseOrAsync(result)) {
        result = null
        throw new TypeError('PromiseOrAsync')
      }
      //#endregion проверка в процессе

    } catch (_e) {
      time = null
      console.log(_e)
    }
    return [time, result]
  }

  function foo() {
    return 'res'
  }
  async function bar() {
    return 'res'
  }

  function baz() {
    return Promise.resolve('res')
  }

  console.log('foo', test(foo)) //foo (2) [0, "res"]

  //TypeError: PromiseOrAsync
  console.log('bar', test(bar)) //bar (2) [null, null]

  //TypeError: PromiseOrAsync
  console.log('baz', test(baz)) //baz (2) [null, null]
}()
```

### `#region проверка на страрте`

конечно, предпочтительнее производить обнаружение TypeError в самом начале выполнения функции, и в случае асинхронных функций это возможно, не не в случае промиса.

**обнаружение асинхронной функции**

я приведу два примера, взятые отсюда [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38510353/4794368)

1. первый пример:

   ```
   if (_f[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'AsyncFunction') throw new TypeError('AsyncFunction')
   ```
2. второй пример:

   ```
   const AsyncFunction = (async () => {}).constructor;
   if (_f instanceof AsyncFunction) throw new TypeError('AsyncFunction')
   ```

и один отсюда [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40539727/4794368)

```
function isAsync (func) {
    const string = func.toString().trim();

    return !!(
        // native
        string.match(/^async /) ||
        // babel (this may change, but hey...)
        string.match(/return _ref[^\.]*\.apply/)
        // insert your other dirty transpiler check

        // there are other more complex situations that maybe require you to check the return line for a *promise*
    );
}
```

**обнаружение промиса**

1. отсуствует

### `#region проверка в процессе`

и так, давайте поговорим о промисах, и что такое 'проверка в процессе'

#### что такое 'проверка в процессе'

вот смотрите, есть функция baz

```
function baz() { return Promise.resolve('res') }
```

это функция, просто функция, самая обыкновенная
но она возвращает промис
но мы об этом не узнаем до тех пор, пока не вызовем её (не берём в расчёт приведённый ранее третий пример)

```js
void function() {
  function baz() {
    return Promise.resolve('res')
  }
  let p = baz()
  console.log('baz', p instanceof Promise) //baz true
  console.log('baz', p.then !== void 0) //baz true //<---категорически не рекомендую
  async function bar() {
    return 'res'
  }
  let a = bar()
  console.log('bar', a instanceof Promise) //bar true
  console.log('bar', a.then !== void 0) //bar true

  let isPromiseOrAsync = (_o) => (_o == Promise.resolve(_o)) //проверка в процессе
  console.log('baz', isPromiseOrAsync(p)) //baz true
  console.log('bar', isPromiseOrAsync(a)) //bar true
}()
```

лично мне приглянулся способ `isPromiseOrAsync` подсмотренный здесь [источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38339199/4794368). автор ответа ссылается на спеки, приводит пруфы и сетует на метод `instanceof` и сафари.